# Obtaining client IP Address through ALUI Portal Gateway

Tags: oracle, ip-address, portal, oracleportal, plumtree

Currently using Oracle/BEA/Plumtree ALUI Portal 6.1, and am trying to display a client's IP Address.  Problem is that since this content is being gatewayed, the portal server's address is coming up when I call

```
<%= request.getRemoteAddr() %> (<%= request.getRemoteHost() %>)
```

I am pretty much doing the java equivalent of [this link](http://www.scribd.com/doc/30729/Chapter-2-Understanding-ALUI-Portal-with-helloworld-Aqualogic-Developers-Notebook), and it's not working correctly.  Uncertain if there is something somewhere in the IDK, or if there's a configuration setting that needs to change.

Comment: Isn't it on a web service preferences page?

Comment: I looked across the settings and didn't see anything listing IP Address as an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is doable using PEIs (Plumtree Event Interfaces). This is a two part process:

- First create a PEI that stores the Client IP Address in the Portal Session. To do this, here is a reference: http://edocs.beasys.com/alui/devdoc/docs5x/Customizing_the_Portal_UI/Using_PEIs/PlumtreeDevDoc_Customizing_PEI_Step2Implement.htm
- Refer to the Portal Session to get the Client IP Address.